# How to (completely) uninstall Code Contracts Tool extension?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-contracts

I'm trying to get rid of Code Contracts Tools extension on my system. I've uninstalled it from "programs and functionalities" yet it still appears as an installed extension inside Visual Studio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't *completely* uninstall Code Contracts, because some parts of the functionality are [built into the .NET framework itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.aspx). Can you clarify exactly what your goals are, and why they were not when you uninstalled Code Contracts from the Programs and Features section of Control Panel?

Comment: @SamHarwell Sorry, I actually was referring to the Code Contracts Tool extension.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The uninstaller does not remove all files that are no longer needed. In particular, the actual VSIX files are never deleted:

- codecontracts_project.png
- codecontracts_SM.png
- extension.vsixmanifest
- license.rtf

These files seem to be a source of trouble when upgrading the tools to a newer version.

To completely uninstall the tools:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio to prevent file locks
2. Remove the tools using the uninstaller listed under "Programs and Features"
3. Delete the extension folder: 
   `<Visual Studio installation folder>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeContracts`

Comment: Thank you, Steven! :) For reference, this issue has been reported on the github project page here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/7

Comment: Even after following these steps, Code Contracts is still visible in the list of installed extensions in VS 2013 update 4, not to mention being also there in the list of available updates.

Comment: okie dokie ... did that, that removed the pretty icon, I still have the Code Contracts Tools showing up in the list of installed.  And before you say (type) have to tried restarting your machine ... yes!  Anybody have further thoughts?

Comment: @THBBFT I had that too, but deleting the extension folder as mentioned above solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but if you stumble in here looking for a way to remove Code Contracts, this is what finally worked for me:

BEFORE DOING ANYTHING: Make sure all instances of Visual studio have been closed on the PC.

1) Uninstall Code Contracts using the Control Panel.

2) Delete the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeContracts.

3) Open the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged with windows note pad, and then click file > Save. Make sure you don't actually make any changes to the file. VS is looking for a change in the last modified date to refresh the extensions.

Now start Visual Studio and make sure the Code Contracts extension is gone from the extensions screen. Like others here I'd done step 1 and 2, and it wasn't working. I gleaned step 3  from from the following post on MSDN:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17d132a3-d2e7-48be-bdca-b0b6421e544a/may-21-2014-release?forum=codecontracts