# Code Contracts version does not update

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've installed an update of Code Contracts but the version of Code Contracts shown in the "Extensions and Updates" window has not changed. However in project properties, the version number has changed.

Why is the current version in "Extensions and Updates" not changing and how I can fix it?

If it helps: I use Windows 7 Enterprise and Visual Studio Professional 2013

**EDIT:**

- I restarted program and computer.
- I have just installed Visual Studio 2013. I do not install older versions of Visual Studio.
- On "Code Contracts" tab in project properties I see a new version number. And I think that the Code Contracts libraries are updated.
- I tried to remove and reinstall Code Contracts. It doesn't help. But I don't want reinstall Visual Studio.

**EDIT 2:**

Extensions and Updates:
[image: Extensions and updates]

Project properties:
[image: Project properties]

Comment: What are the two versions you're seeing and where exactly are you getting the numbers from?  Perhaps some screenshots showing them would be useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the uninstaller as described in [this MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17d132a3-d2e7-48be-bdca-b0b6421e544a/may-21-2014-release?forum=codecontracts) by user [Manuel Pallier](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/manuel%20pallier/?ws=usercard-mini)

Check if you have two folders in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeContracts`, one with the old version number and one with the new one.

Follow these steps to clean-up all versions and then reinstall the correct version of Code Contracts:

1. Uninstall Code Contracts via the control panel.
2. Delete the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeContracts.`
3. Touch the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged` (touching means updating its last modified date; just open it in an editor and save it without changes). This step is required so that Visual Studio rebuilds its extension database on the next start.
4. Start Visual Studio and make sure the Code Contracts extension is gone from the extensions screen.
   4b. Click *Uninstall* if it hasn't (might be the case for 1.8.x -> 1.9.x)
   Then close Visual Studio again.
5. Install the new version.
6. Start Visual Studio and make sure it shows the new version in the extensions screen.

There is a similar [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27527902/578411) from user [Steven Liekens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288449/steven-liekens) that seems to confirm that the uninstaller is flaky.

Uninstalling Visual Studio seems **NOT** to be the way to solve so don't go down that route.

Comment: Thanks, @rene. It works! Sorry for offtop, what does mean flaky? It like strange or odd?

Comment: @Vlad I used the word to mean unreliable (at least that is one of the options urbandictionary gave for me)

Comment: Thank you, @rene! :) In my case, I didn't have to uninstall code contracts. I just had to delete the folder with the old version number and touch extensions.configurationchanged.  This issue has been reported on the github project page here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/7

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the wonderful detailed answer which solved the issue. Just an addittion, from version 1.8.x to 1.9.x I had to insert a 4B step. When opening Visual Studio to make sure that the Code Contracts extension is gone, I found it wasn't gone. I just had to click on "Uninstall" button (which was now enabled) and it was gone. Then continued with step 5 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.9.10714.2 seems to have a bad vsixmanifest file.
I did all the above and then edited

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\CodeContracts\1.9.10714.2\extension.vsixmanifest and corrected the version number.
Re-touched the extensions.configurationchanged file and VS accepted that the version installed was upto date.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found an Identity Version number mismatch in the manifest file after all the steps mentioned above, installing **1.9.10714.2**, as you can see below:

...Identity Version="**1.8.10107.10**"...

I fixed the Identity Version number and I solved the problem.